# How to find a definite integral over a symmetric interval without finding the antiderivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

How do I find the following without finding the anti derivative
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \ln(x^2+1)e^{\sin \lvert x\rvert}\sin x dx 
$$

Answer (score 12):

I'm assuming that the integral exists and is finite. Take the integrand as $f(x)$.

Note that, $f(-x)=-f(x)\iff f(x)\textrm{ is odd}$.

Hence, we have,

$$I=\int\limits_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)=0$$

Comment: @John, Thanks for correcting the typo. :)

Comment: Why would the integral not exist? It's a continuous function on a closed, bounded interval.

Answer (score 4):

That is an odd function. So, the answer must simply be zero.

Answer (score 2):

Interval $[-\pi,\pi]$ is symmetric about the origin and
$$\ln(x^2+1)e^{\sin \lvert x\rvert}$$
is even, but $\sin x$ is odd, thus the integrand function is odd. Then, the integral is $0$.